# Swift - SpriteKit how do I do infinite background scrolling with two unique backgrounds?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

My code works perfectly fine for one common background but I am unable to figure out the required logic have it working perfectly fine if the backgrounds were unique.

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView)
{
    createBackground()
}

func createBackground ()
{
    var texture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "card1")
    let texture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "card2")

    for i in 0...1
    {
        let background = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture1)
        background.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero

        background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: texture1.size().height * CGFloat(i))
        addChild(background)

        let moveDown = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -background.size.height, duration: 5)
        let reset = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: background.size.height, duration: 0)
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveDown, reset])
        let forever = SKAction.repeatForever(sequence)

        background.run(forever)

        texture1 = texture2
    }

}
```

}

Comment: By unique you mean two different background? Ex. one blue background and one yellow background?

Comment: Yeah, I don't mind adding another green background as a 3rd background etc